# Check if a document exists on Firestore without get() the full document data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So this is possible:

```
const docSnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("SOME_COL").doc("SOME_DOC").get();
console.log(docSnapshot.exists);
```

But it "downloads" the whole document just to check if it exists. And I'm currently working with some havier documents and I have a script where I just need to know if they exist, but I don't need to download them at that time.

Is there a way to check if a document exist without `.get()` and avoid downloading the document data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the JavaScript SDK. With this SDK there isn't any way to only get a subset of the fields of a document.

One of the possible solutions is to maintain another collection with documents that have the same IDs than the main collection documents but which only hold a very small dummy field. You could use a set of [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to synchronise the two collections (Documents creation/deletion).

---

On the other hand, with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.documents), it is possible, with the [`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get) method, to define a [`DocumentMask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) which defines a "set of field paths on a document" and is "used to restrict a get  operation on a document **to a subset of its fields**". Depending on your exact use case, this can be an interesting and easier solution.

Comment: Hi, 2 years and half later, is this still impossible to do with the JS SDK? Thanks

Comment: @clementlize yes it is still impossible